# как получить случайное число без повторений в bash

Tags: bash

```
myarr=()


for i in {0..25}; do

    myarr+=($(shuf -i 1-$POST_NUM -n 1))

done


for i in ${!myarr[@]}; do

    echo ${myarr[$i]}

done
```

я собираю массив из случайных чисел с помощью `$(shuf -i 1-$POST_NUM -n 1)`

но в массиве оказываются два одинаковых числа а иногда и идущие подряд,
в моем случае это не допустимо .
как сделать массив без повторяющихся чисел ?

Comment: `$(shuf -i 1-$POST_NUM -n 1 | uniq)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как сделать массив без повторяющихся чисел ?

здесь:

```
myarr=()
for i in {0..25}; do
    myarr+=($(shuf -i 1-$POST_NUM -n 1))
done
```

вы в цикле 26 раз запускаете программу *shuf*, для того чтобы каждый раз получить по одному числу (`-n 1`). естественно, эти числа могут повторяться.

вызывайте программу *shuf* один раз, получая все 26 чисел сразу:

```
myarr=($(shuf -i 1-$POST_NUM -n 26))
```